# Excel - Sort Columns of Differing Length That Adds Blank Cells when No Match Is Found

Tags: excel, sorting, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet with four total columns of data. One set is the product SKU and on hand quantities for a brick and mortar store and the other set is for the website. The two sets of product SKUs have different item count totals. I have googled to see if it was possible to sort the lists to make them even (SKU = SKU) by filling in blanks where no match is found. It seems to be but I have yet to find anything concrete on what to actually DO.

For example, if I have a group that looks like this in the spreadsheet:

```
SKU1 0 SKU1 2
SKU2 2 SKU3 2
SKU3 3 SKU8 5
```

I need it to look like this:

```
SKU1 0 SKU1 2
SKU2 2     
SKU3 2 SKU3 3
       SKU8 5
```

I checked several Excel forums and several links here. I checked these: [Compare columns of unequal length for matches and differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747058/compare-columns-of-unequal-length-for-matches-and-differences), http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/877911-sort-and-match-uneven-columns-of-data.html, http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/608313-sorting-with-unequal-cell-size.html. This link was close: https://superuser.com/questions/307429/how-do-i-line-up-two-sets-of-data-in-excel. However, I don't think it quite achieves my goal, but it's possible I'm just not sure of the information given (I'm no Excel pro, which is why I'm asking).

If I need to provide the spreadsheet for further context, I can do so.

This seems to be a common type of question, but I have yet to find anything solid that fully explains it. If I follow the information right, "VLOOKUP" is what I want, but I don't fully understand it.

[EDIT] Forgot to mention, I do need both lists as I need to identify the differences in quantity between each list. That, I think I can do already, but I need the list sorted as desired for better comparison.

Comment: Why not just have Three columns on your output; SKU,B and M,Online,  The you would simply copy and paste bot sku lists into the first and use Remove Duplicates to get the unique and then a simple VLOOKUP to get the qty from each list with an IFERROR to deal when on is not found in that respective list.

Comment: That would work, but I edited my post for a bit of clarification. I need to keep both lists so I can run a comparison between online store and brick and mortar store to see what differences there are.